# what's the property of concat function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For concatenation functions such as $f(\vec{p}) =(\vec{p},\vec{p})$ or $g(\vec{p}) =(\vec{p},\vec{1}-\vec{p})$. where $\vec{p}, \vec{1}-\vec{p} \in P \subseteq [0,1]^n $.
What's the property of it? is it convex? how should I approach it?

What my context is that $\vec{p} \in P$ where $P$ is a convex set.
And I have a convex function $l$ where ${\displaystyle l\colon \,P\times P\mapsto \mathbb {R}}$.

For the composed function $l(g(\vec{p}))$ can i claim that

$
{\displaystyle {\underset {\vec{x}\in P}{\operatorname {arg\,max} }}\,l(g(\vec{x}))\in \text{closure of} convexhull(P) }
$ ?

Comment: Convexity is a property of real-valued functions. Your functions are vector-valued, so it does not make sense to ask if they are convex. Perhaps you want to ask if $l \circ f$ or $l \circ g$ are convex whenever $l$ is convex?

Comment: Sorry I just added more context into the problem.

Comment: Also, what is $1-\vec{p}$? Are you assuming $\vec{p}\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: it's $\vec{1}$, sorry about the confusion

Comment: You are assuming $P$ is convex, so the convex hull of $P$ is just $P$. This seems to make the conclusion you're trying to prove trivial...

Comment: why would $ P \times 1-P $ carries the information ?

Comment: $l(g(\vec{x}))$ is a function defined on $P$, not on $P \times (1-P)$. The expression you wrote is $\arg\max_{\vec{x} \in P} l(g(\vec{x}))$. By definition, since you are taking an argmax over $\vec{x} \in P$, you must get something in $P$.

Comment: yes, but then $g(\vec{p})$ would carrier over the convexity?

Comment: Whether $l(g(\vec{p}))$ is convex is a different issue. There's also the question of whether $l(g(\vec{p}))$ is well-defined on all of $P$. Namely, you need $\vec{1}-\vec{p} \in P$.

Comment: i've already updated the details, so both $\vec{p} \in P$ and $\vec{1}-\vec{p} \in P$

Answer (score 1):

> For concatenation functions such as $f(\vec{p}) =(\vec{p},\vec{p})$ or $g(\vec{p}) =(\vec{p},\vec{1}-\vec{p})$. where $\vec{p}, \vec{1}-\vec{p} \in P \subseteq [0,1]^n $.
>   What's the property of it? is it convex?

Vector-valued functions do not have a notion of convexity, so no.

> For the composed function $l(g(\vec{p}))$ can i claim that
>   $
> {\displaystyle {\underset {\vec{x}\in P}{\operatorname {arg\,max} }}\,l(g(\vec{x}))\in convexhull(P) }
> $ ?

By definition, if you take the argmax over $\vec{x} \in P$, you will get out an element $\vec{x}_0 \in P$. Since $P$ is convex, it is equal to its convex hull and the result trivially holds.

Perhaps you want to know whether $l(f(\vec{p}))$ or $l(g(\vec{p}))$ are convex. That is, does it hold that
$$l(f(t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2)) \leq t l(f(\vec{p}_1)) + (1-t) l(f(\vec{p}_2)) \forall t \in [0,1]$$
and similarly for $g$. For $f$, notice that
$$f(t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2) = (t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2,t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2)= t(\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_1)+(1-t)(\vec{p}_2,\vec{p}_2).$$
Now use the convexity of $l$.

For $g$ it is a little trickier, but you can show that
\begin{align*}
g(t\vec{p}_1,(1-t)\vec{p}_2)&=(t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2, \vec{1}-(t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2))\\
&= (t\vec{p}_1+(1-t)\vec{p}_2, t (\vec{1}-\vec{p}_1) + (1-t)(\vec{1}-\vec{p}_2))\\
&= t(\vec{p}_1, \vec{1}-\vec{p}_1) + (1-t) (\vec{p}_2, \vec{1}-\vec{p}_2).
\end{align*}
Now again use the convexity of $l$.

Comment: sorry i was referring to the closure of convex hull instead of convex hull :(